# How to let Google know that content on the page has just changed?

Tags: seo, search-engine-indexing

I'd never thought of such a problem in the whole SEO spectrum before I considered launching my own website.

Imagine that I have a website which is updated once per month and Google spider knows about that. So what happens if I've updated one of my pages with new content just after it was crawled? Do I need to wait for a month before Google spider will come back?
And is it possible that someone can find my website by queries which are not already relevant to it?

Has anybody encountered such problem or has a solution?

Comment: How often does Google crawl your site now?

Comment: Get good backlinks to your web site and you won't need to let Google know when your web pages change.

Answer (score 4):

There's a few things you can do:

1. On Webmaster Tools, Go to "Health" / "Fetch as Google" where you can enter the address of the page that has changed, click on "Fetch" then click on "Submit to index". At which point a message will pop up and say: "Select if your page is new or has been recently updated. Google doesn't guarantee to index all submitted URLs." Choose your option, and hit OK.
2. Resubmit sitemap.
3. Adjust crawl frequency.

I always go to step 1 when I change something on a page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google's Webmaster tools to adjust the frequency with which Google crawls your site.

Comment: A few points on this however. You can make a recommendation to Google about updating the frequency of the crawl of your site however it is not bound to adhere to this. As you say yourself, Google learns about update frequency from the site itself so regularly updated sites get crawled more frequently as they have more changed information more regularly. A month is a short time in SEO in the overall picture of things!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you will need to prepare a sitemap. Sitemap is nothing just a map of your site which will list each page of your website. It tells search engines that about your new pages.
Then you have to tell submit these sitemap to Google Webmaster Tools.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an XML sitemap, you can specify a lastmod tag like below and it gives a hint to the search engine crawler when the page has last been updated:

```
<url>

  <loc>http://www.example.com/</loc>

  <lastmod>2005-01-01</lastmod>

  <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>

  <priority>0.8</priority>

</url>
```

Even though your page may have just been crawled, the search engine may take notice of your sitemap last modified tag and crawl the page again.

Answer (score -1):

In this case you can use various ping options available just to let Google know about your particular page being updated on your site.

Use any of the following site ping to Google server.

http://www.pingler.com/

http://pingomatic.com/

http://googleping.com/

Comment: This works for blog search engines, including Google Blog Search, but not for Google's main index or other general search engines.